# Limit webkit-overflow-scrolling

Tags: css, mobile-webkit

I have a `div` that needs to scroll horizontally. This works fine without `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`, but I don’t get the native bouncing on the iPhone. It only scrolls horizontally, not vertically, as I want.

When I add the CSS property and set it to `touch`, it scrolls horizontally as expected. However, it also scrolls vertically. The thing is, it looks like the scrollable area is the same as the viewable area – i.e., the content bounces in each direction, but there is no content that should make it scroll. Can I limit this scrolling to horizontal only?

Note: `overflow-y` is set to `hidden`, and `overflow-x` is `scroll`. I have verified in the web inspector that all elements have a height of 100px, so I don't believe that there are any elements that are causing the scrolling.

Comment: Can you make an example page to show the problem ? Im not sure 100% what you mean

Comment: the problem is on mobile?

Comment: Related: [Stop overscroll when using “-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14307324/578288)

Comment: Here's an example page.  http://jsfiddle.net/szal/uBnwp/12/embedded/result/ - Sorry about the too-far zoom out, but I'd like the middle horizontal boxes on this page to not allow vertical scrolling on iOS Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this piece of code. This will enable scrolling.

```
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

OR

```
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
```

Now you should be able to scroll. If this is not what you exactly looking for then attach a sample page.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that, but how do you take that and disable vertical scrolling wtihin that region?  I only want horizontal scrolling; vertical scrolling of the whole page should remain in effect.

Comment: Then you must try this,
`overflow-y:hidden;` - Hides the Vertical scroll and `overflow-x:auto;` - Shows horizontal scroll

Comment: As mentioned above, we care not about showing scrollbars, but about the behavior on a touch device.  Also, overflow-y:hidden; is already set, per above.

Comment: Here's an example page. http://jsfiddle.net/szal/uBnwp/12/embedded/result - Sorry about the too-far zoom out, but I'd like the middle horizontal boxes on this page to not allow vertical scrolling on iOS Mobile Safari.

Comment: Now take a look, probably this is what you looking  [http://jsfiddle.net/uBnwp/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/uBnwp/13/)