# Stop overscroll when using "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch"?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

I've found the:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

css element to give us native scrolling on ios. This seems to work ok for me.

But is there a way to turn off the "overscroll" effect?

For example, when scroll position = zero, and you keep dragging downwards, the top of my content will move downwards revealing a little bit of white space above it. When you release your finger, the content snaps back upwards. Is there a way to disable just that portion of it?

Also I read from here:

http://cantina.co/2012/03/06/ios-5-native-scrolling-grins-and-gothcas/

that apple had introduced this with a bug related to rendering, and a hack fix of:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

is supposed to fix it. Was that fixed with ios6?

Comment: Wasn't aware of the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` property. Quite interesting.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have you tried the techniques in [this blog post](http://www.deadmarshes.com/Blog/20110804114957.html) about turning off elastic scrolling? Specifically, for iOS it suggests the following JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener(
  'touchmove',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: Globally disabling 'touchmove' makes it impossible to scroll down the page at all.

Comment: You can however add this to specific elements, like a `position:fixed` button.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to help:

https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix

> ... ScrollFix works around this by manually offsetting the scrollTop value
>   to one away from the limit at either extreme, which causes the browser
>   to use rubber banding rather than passing the event up the DOM tree.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for this. I was wracking my brain over this bizarre issue and this solved it quite effectively!